# how to add google analytics code in template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, google-analytics

I have i one template file call abc.php and using this template only for 1 page now i want to add google conversion tracking code in  section. If i add code before get_header(); function then it shows before  tag and if i put after get_header(); then it shows in  tag.

Please help me as i want to use conversion code only for 1 particular page so i can't add this code in header.php

```
 <?php
  /* Template Name: Cost_Estimation_Result */ 
  ?>
   <!-- Event snippet for Website lead conversion page -->
   <script>
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': '*********************'});
   </script>
   <?php
   get_header();
   ?>
```

Comment: You can read this article as well : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cdynamic-websit

Comment: Thanks but this article doesn't solved my problem

Comment: in simple way you can duplicate the header and only use that, also we have some hooks for this, you can search it on codex

Answer (score 0):

Add this javascript

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
    
    
    script.innerHTML = "your analytics code";
    
    // Append to head
    
    document.head.appendChild(script);
```

try this not sure if it will work though , another way if u get string from get_header() and append gtag part before loading in your page like this :

```
  $header = str_get_html(get_header());
    $gtag  = "<script>
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': '*********************'});
   </script>";



 $header->find('head', 0)->innertext = $gtag.$header->find('head', 0)->innertext;
```

reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/18187111/8719734

Answer (score 0):

Add Below code in function.php solved my problem.

```
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpsites_add_tracking_code' );
 function wpsites_add_tracking_code() {
    if ( is_page(200) ) {
       echo'<div class="tracking-code">add your tracking code here.</div>';
    } 
  }
```